# Writing utf8 strings in oracle CLOB stream gives additional spaces (node.js)

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I use node.js, oracle and oracledb module. Also I have a simple PL/SQL procedure like this

```
    procedure mock_lobs(
        P_CLOB  IN OUT CLOB,
        P_BLOB  IN OUT BLOB
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
      NULL;
    END mock_lobs;
```

It returns exactly what has been passed.

Then I create a temporary CLOB object using API `clob = connection.createLob(oracledb.CLOB)`
and populate it with some unicode string chunks (several iterations) like this `clob.write(chunk)`

After the clob is passed to procedure execution I receive resulting CLOB object and try to read it. I see my chunks were written with additional spaces after each one. When I write a string like `"abcЩ"` with length of 4 symbols it's written as `"abcЩ "` (tailing spaces for each non-ASCII symbol). In other words size of written chunk equals the number of bytes the original strings takes.

I've tried to specify `utf8` encoding for clob like this: `clob.setEncoding('utf8')` and even while writing `clob.write(chunk, 'utf8')` but result is always the same.

What's the problem explanation? What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-oracledb` mantainers confirmed it is a bug. So, we'll be up for next releases!